# DataFrame filtering in Streamlit returns empty result for condition that works in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, whatsapp, streamlit

I am developing a WhatsApp analysis web app using Streamlit. One of the functionalities of the app is to count the number of media messages in a given WhatsApp chat. To achieve this, I have a DataFrame containing the chat data, including a 'message' column that stores the text of each message.

In my code, I am using the following line to count the number of media messages:

```
no_of_media = df[df['message'] == '<Media omitted>\n'].shape[0]
```

This code works perfectly fine when I run it in Jupyter Notebook. However, when I integrate it into my Streamlit app and run the app, the code always returns a count of 0 for media messages, even when I know there are media messages present in the chat data.

To investigate the issue, I added some debug statements in my Streamlit app and found that the DataFrame obtained from the data source in Streamlit appears to be empty or does not contain any rows that match the condition df['message'] == '\n'. However, when I print the DataFrame in Jupyter Notebook, I can see the expected rows matching the condition.

I have verified that the data loading in Streamlit is correct and that the correct file is being read. Additionally, I have checked the 'message' column values in Streamlit and compared them with what I observed in the notebook. There seem to be no apparent differences in the values.

Despite these attempts to debug and troubleshoot, I am still unable to identify why the code is not working as expected in Streamlit and always returning a count of 0 for media messages.

Any help or insights on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You have basically have tracked down the issues. (Re-read your paragraph that is third from the bottom and the fourth from the bottom.) Keep hacking at it or improve your post significantly. We cannot tell anything more than you because you aren't sharing reproducible code or details of your system. You should look into whether the same versions of Python and all associated modules are being used. Keep in mind you are not filtering in streamlit. You are in Python running along with Streamlit. Please read and follow [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

```
no_of_media = df[df['message'].str.contains('<Media omitted>')].shape[0]
```

use this instead of other one in question

Comment: Please explain why this change worked, and why the previous version did not. What is it about the Streamlit vs Jupyter environments required this change?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).